# How to create an or operator in regex?

Tags: javascript, jquery, regex, match, src

I have a function that loops over `script` tags and tries to match their src based on a url.

```
$('script').each(function(index) {
    var com = this.src.match(/use\.typekit\.com\/(.+)\.js/);
});
```

Currently, the above script only supports `.com` typekit urls. I want to support `.net` too.

I have tried this:

```
$('script').each(function(index) {
    var com = this.src.match(/use\.typekit\(.com|.net)\/(.+)\.js/);
});
```

But that failed, can someone please help me out and also explain how to add it?

Comment: Why are you escaping the parenthesis? That makes it a literal.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to escape a dot with \ in group:

```
var com = this.src.match(/use\.typekit\.(com|net)\/(.+)\.js/);
```

Changed it a bit to what Zeeker pointed out.

Comment: ... `typekit\.(com|net)` ... would be less redundant.

Answer (score 2):

You want `.` to mean "a `.` character" and you want the `(` to mean "The start of a  group" so you need to escape the `.` characters, not the `(`.

```
 typekit(\.com|\.net)
```